# React decorator with dynamic param

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a simple decorator and a react native component that is decorated like this:

```
@withData('apple')
class Screen extends Component {
}
```

I need to pass the parameter to @widhData dynamically. Based on the screen user has selected. But outside class I don't have access to props and so on.
How can pass dynamic parameters to the decorator based on the param passed on navigation ?

Thanks.

Comment: If that's a param, pass it simply as a prop.

Comment: but I can't pass to @withData(props.etc)

Comment: just access `this.props.params` from the withData HOC

Comment: but the param is 'apple', 'banana', etc. I need to change the @withData params with dynamic param